Are abbreviated demonyms such as "Indon", "Viet", and "Bangla" derogatory in the white countries?
In Singapore, one often refers to "Indons", "Viets", "Banglas", and "Japs" (persons from Indonesia, Viet Nam, Bangladesh, and Japan).
I understand that "Jap" is considered derogatory in the white countries (US, UK, CA, AU, NZ, IE) because during WW2, it became a common racist slur in the US.
In Singapore, "Bangla" is now often considered derogatory among more educated/modern/westernized/woke Singaporeans because there are 150,000+ low-wage and often marginalized Bangladeshis (2.5%+ of the population) who clean and build the city.
Similarly, educated Singaporeans know about "Jap" being derogatory in the West and so may avoid it.
But generally, "Indons", "Viets", and "Japs" aren't considered derogatory in Singapore. Less "educated/sophisticated" Singaporeans will often say, "Let's have Jap!" to simply mean let's have Japanese food for lunch without any derogatory intent.
My Q: Are "Indon", "Viet", "Bangla", and other similar abbreviated demonyms generally "automatically" considered derogatory and unacceptable in the white-majority English-speaking countries? Or are they acceptable until they've been excessively used in racist contexts (such as with "Jap")?

Sometimes abbreviating a name is offensive because it shows the speaker does not care enough to use the full word.

I have seen Bangla used as completely neutral, closer to source language, Latin-alphabet-based spelling of বাংলা (/baŋla/, [ˈbaŋlaˑ]), which refers to language or region. Terms "Bengal" and "Bengali" are corruptions borrowed to English through Persian and Portuguese. There is e.g. software project called OpenBangla, whose intention is to allow writing in script for that language.

@Peter: But are Brit and Aussie considered offensive?

@user103496, as an Australian I don't believe Aussie is offensive in most contexts, perhaps because we have adopted the word ourselves. I can't speak for Brit.

I note there is a vote to close. While this question is not really about English language structure and vocabulary, is is implicitly about how some words can appropriately be used, i.e. usage.

BrE: Bangla does not appear to be pejorative

@AndrewLeach: 2024 "Bangla beats" - I think that's used in the sense of the Bangla language (plus that's a show hosted and probably named by a Bangladeshi) // 2019 "Bangla Bantams" - again, a football team named by Bangladeshis themselves // Ignoring such self-naming (another is about the hygiene issues of one "Bangla Supermarket"), the most recent use of "Bangla" is in 2000: in the headline "Bangla talks rejected" (where Bangla seems to be an abbreviation for Bangladesh)

There is a lot of difference between what's offensive in the UK, US, and Australia: you can't generalize. Also, by saying Five Eyes I guess you're not referring to the intelligence agencies but that's what your link says: maybe don't use misleading jargon.

Also it'll depend a lot on which ethnic group is speaking or being referred to. So it's a very big question to cover comprehensively. Best bet is always to ask members of the ethnic group how they like to be addressed, but you may get multiple answers.

This is definitely complicated. In the US there has been a progressive movement to stop using epithets related to Native Americans as sports team names (e.g. Chiefs, Redskins, etc.), but much of the indigenous community thinks these are minor issues.
